# awk to update value in field of out file using contents of another

Tags: awk

In the `out.txt` below I am trying to use `awk` to update the contents of `$9`. The `out.txt` is created by the `awk` before the pipe `|`.  If `$9` contains a `+` or `-` then `$8` of `out.txt` is used as a key to lookup in `$2` of `file2`. When a match ( there will always be one) is found the `$3` value of that `file2` is used to update `$9` of `out.txt` seperated by a `:`.  So the original `+6` in `out.txt` would be `+6:NM_005101.3`. The `awk` below is close but has syntax errors after the `|` that I can not seem to fix.  Thank you :).

**out.txt** `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  Inheritence ExonicFunc.IDP.refGene  AAChange.IDP.refGene
1   chr1    948846  948846  -   A   upstream    ISG15   -0     .    .   .
2   chr1    948870  948870  C   G   UTR5    ISG15   NM_005101.3:c.-84C>G    .   .
4   chr1    949925  949925  C   T   downstream  ISG15   +6  .   .   .
5   chr1    207646923   207646923   G   A   intronic    CR2 >50 .   .   .
8   chr1    948840  948840  -   C   upstream    ISG15   -6  .   .   .
```

file2 `space-delimited`

```
2 ISG15 NM_005101.3 948846-948956 949363-949919
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited'

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene  Inheritence ExonicFunc.IDP.refGene  AAChange.IDP.refGene
1   chr1    948846  948846  -   A   upstream    ISG15   -0:NM_005101.3  .   .   .
2   chr1    948870  948870  C   G   UTR5    ISG15   NM_005101.3:c.-84C>G    .   .
4   chr1    949925  949925  C   T   downstream  ISG15   +6:NM_005101.3  .   .   .
5   chr1    207646923   207646923   G   A   intronic    CR2 >50 .   .   .
8   chr1    948840  948840  -   C   upstream    ISG15   -6:NM_005101.3  .   .   .
```

**Description**

```
lines 1, 3, 5 `$9` updated with`: ` and value of `$3` in `file2`
line 2 and 4 are skipped as these do not have a `+` or `-` in them
```

**awk**

```
awk -v extra=50 -v OFS='\t' '
NR == FNR {
count[$2] = $1
for(i = 1; i <= $1; i++) {
low[$2, i] = $(2 + 2 * i)
high[$2, i] = $(3 + 2 * i)
mid[$2, i] = (low[$2, i] + high[$2, i]) / 2
}
next
}
    FNR != 1 && $9 == "." && $12 == "." && $8 in count {
    for(i = 1; i <= count[$8]; i++)
    if($4 >= (low[$8, i] - extra) && $4 <= (high[$8, i] + extra)) {
    if($4 > mid[$8, i]) {
    sign = "+"
    value = high[$8, i]
} 
    else {
    sign = "-"
    value = low[$8, i]
}
    diff = (value > $4) ? value - $4 : $4 - value
    $9 = (diff > 50) ? ">50" : (sign diff)
    break
}
   if(i > count[$8]) {
   $9 = ">50"
}
   }
   1
   ' FS='[- ]' file2 FS='\t' file1 | awk if($6 == "-" || $6 == "+") printf ":" ; 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$3; next} a[$8]{$3=a[$8]}1' OFS='\t' file2 > final.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Yes, I need to indent is there a standard format or is indenting done by block, or something else. Thank you :).

Comment: I indented the `awk` in the post as well as got rid of the `if` syntax error but got an unexpected token. Am I calling the second `awk` correctly?   The second `awk' performs the lookup for the `out.txt` to `file2`, then updates.  Thank you :).

Comment: although you bumped in a few lines of code here and there, it's still not useful indentation. When you indent code it's to show the logical relationship between lines so code what's inside an `if` or `for` or  `while` block would be indented, etc. wrt syntax of your second script, idk how you can know the syntax to write the first script but have no idea how to write the second but to start with change what you have to `awk '$6 == "-" || $6 == "+"{printf ":"} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3; next} a[$8]{$3=a[$8]}1'` idk if that makes any sense semantically but it should remove the syntax error message FWIW.

Comment: I will read more most on indenting.... thank you:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your awk code is OK and your bash usage is wrong.

```
FS='[- ]' file2 FS='\t' file1 |
  awk if($6 == "-" || $6 == "+")
      printf ":" ;
  'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$3; next}
   a[$8]{$3=a[$8]}1' OFS='\t' file2 > final.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I don't know what that's supposed to do.  This for sure, though: on the second line, the awk code needs to be quoted (`awk 'if(....`).  The bash error message stems from the fact that bash is interpreting the (unquoted) awk code, and `(` is not a valid shell-script token after `if`.

Comment: Thank you both very much :).